# Folland Real Analysis Exercise 6.40

Tags: real-analysis

Well, I have been looking for the solution for a few days. But find nothing.

It is about the **decreasing rearrangement**.

If $f$ is a measurable function on $X$, its **decreasing rearrangement** is the function $f^*:(0, \infty)\to [0, \infty]$ defined by $$f^*(t)=\inf\{\alpha:\lambda_f(\alpha)\leq t\}~~~~(\mathrm{where}~\inf\{\varnothing\}=\infty).$$

**a.** $f$ is decreasing. If $f^*(t)<\infty$ then $\lambda_f(f^*(t))\leq t,$ and if $\lambda_f(\alpha)<\infty$ then $f^*(\lambda_f(\alpha))\leq \alpha.$

**b.** $\lambda_f=\lambda_{f^*}$, where $\lambda_{f^*}$ is defined with respect to Lebesgue measure on $(0, \infty)$.

I am struggling in the problem **b**.
I am tending to prove that $f^*$ is right continuous and with the property that it is decreasing, (so to some extends it resembles the distribution function of $f$) I can discuss $f^*$ more specifically. Just like what I did to the distribution function $\lambda_f(\alpha)$.

But it seems not to work. I can not use the same method which I use in proving problem **a** about $\lambda_f(\alpha)$ to solve the $f^*$-question.

And I am always trying to prove this directly by its definition. I don't know if there is an elegant method or theorem to prove the conclusion.

Comment: Well, with the help of my classmate, it seems that there is a solution to this problem. we should first consider the LHS is a constant and tend to prove that the RHS equals to the left. Note that f^* is decreasing so the RHS in fact, is a Lebesgue measure of an interval. So what we should do is to prove the right endpoint of the interval is the LHS which is plausible.